# laravel search in other table on json column by relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

i try make code for search and this is my code:

```
$services = Service::query()->with('plans')->latest();


    if ($request->service_name) {
               $services = $services->whereRaw("CONVERT(JSON_EXTRACT(name, '$.ar') using 'utf8') LIKE  '%$request->service_name%' ")
                ->orWhereRaw("CONVERT(JSON_EXTRACT(name, '$.en') using 'utf8') LIKE  '%$request->service_name%' ")
                ->orWhereRaw("CONVERT(JSON_EXTRACT(name, '$.he') using 'utf8') LIKE  '%$request->service_name%' ");     
    }

        if ($request->plan_name) {
            $plan_name = $request->plan_name;
            $services = $services->whereHas('plans', function ($q) use ($plan_name) {
                $q->where('name->en','Like','%'.$plan_name.'%');
            });
       }

        return $services->get();
```

but when I send plan_name in request the code filters by service name and not by plan name

i tried when is send the plan name in the request The code filter data by plan name but it does not work

Comment: Can you show us `$request`?
Is it possible that `$request->service_name` comes back as `true`, thus changing your `$services` variable, and making it impossible to use again on your 2nd `if` statement?
In any case, I think it's not good to do `$services = $services->...`. It's more likely to have unexpected results this way

Comment: You should use not null with this, ex `if ($request->service_name && !$request->plan_name) {`

Comment: @tola this it the request: 
service_name: 
plan_name: Te

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($request->service_name && !$request->plan_name) { // When only service name provided
    $services = $services->whereRaw("CONVERT(JSON_EXTRACT(name, '$.ar') using 'utf8') LIKE  '%$request->service_name%' ")
            ->orWhereRaw("CONVERT(JSON_EXTRACT(name, '$.en') using 'utf8') LIKE  '%$request->service_name%' ")
            ->orWhereRaw("CONVERT(JSON_EXTRACT(name, '$.he') using 'utf8') LIKE  '%$request->service_name%' ");
}

if ($request->plan_name && !$request->service_name) { // When only plan name provided
    $plan_name = $request->plan_name;
    $services = $services->whereHas('plans', function ($q) use ($plan_name) {
        $q->where('name->en','Like','%'.$plan_name.'%');
    });
}
```

> FYI: You can write this code better than this. This is just fixing your code only.

Answer (score 0):

In several places you have used `->whereRaw("... LIKE '%$request->service_name%' ")` this must be replace with `->whereRaw("... LIKE '%{$request->service_name}%' ")`, notice the `{...}` around `{$request->...}`. What you were doing it converts the whole `$request` to string but you only want a particular param like `service_name`.

By the way I have to point out this implementation is **extremely bad** and should be prohibited because you are exposing your system to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), meaning an attacker could easily read/destroy your database. You should see [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#selectraw) on how to setup query binding, it is pretty easy.